# Recorrer tabla jerarquica/anidada hasta el primer padre

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la tabla **tipodocumento** como una tabla anidada/jerarquica/heredada (desconozco el nombre correcto) que tiene los siguientes campos:

```
-id
-nombre
-padre_id
-...
```

los datos que tengo son:

```
1 | local        | 0
2 | contable     | 1
3 | caja_2019    | 2
4 | caja_2020    | 2
5 | certificados | 0
```

lo que quiero es recorrer cada fila y concatenarla con el nombre del padre de modo que me devuelvan una ruta donde insertare archivos. tengo esta consulta:

```
WITH RECURSIVE niveles AS (
        SELECT 
             nombre
        FROM tipodocumento
        WHERE padre_id = 0

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            CONCAT(td.tNombre, '/', td2.tNombre )
        FROM tipodocumento td
        INNER JOIN tipodocumento td2 ON td.id= td2.padre_id 
)
SELECT *
FROM niveles
```

y los valores que me devuelven son

- local
- local/contable
- contable/caja_2019
- contable/caja_2020
- local/certificados

y aunque algunos están bien, otros no recorre hasta el primer padre. como podría solucionar eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encontre la solucion, la dejo por si le sirve a alguien:

```
with recursive cte (id, nombre, padre_id) as (

    SELECT id, nombre, padre_id
    FROM tipodocumento 
    WHERE padre_id = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT td.id, CONCAT(c.nombre, '/', td.nombre), td.padre_id
    FROM tipodocumento td
    INNER JOIN cte c ON td.padre_id = c.id
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: No olvides marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema es que no existe el elemento con id 0, debes asegurarte de  que existan todas las ID y seria bueno que definieras hasta cuantos niveles son

Comment: la idea de la tabla es que no tenga un limite de niveles. el 0 viene a ser la raiz, apartir de la raiz, el resto de carpetas seran creadas.